# z-index is not working responsive and position fixed sidebar

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

i got stuck in css, 
I am implementing sidebar(toggle)  and modal,
But its not working.

```
.show-modal{
  z-index: 2147483647;
  background:rgba(1,1,1,0.5);
}
```

This is the css i gave to modal

```
.left-menu{
    width: 240px;
    height: calc(100% - 55px);
    //background: @gray-3;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This is css i gave to the sidebar.

what i am getting is

[Here is my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhewK.png)

Please help me,
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: I wanted to hide sidebar when modal is open @user0101

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Pleaae, help me to solve this @Paulie_D

Comment: It seems like CSS related question. If you want to hide sidebar when modal is visible you would have to look into JS solution

Comment: Can you please let me know how its done? @user0101,
Can't be done with z-index.
sideBar will be shown but with backdrop

Comment: Sorry, I don't even know what you HTML looks like